# Setup Apache server for testing a web app

Tags: java, javascript, apache, web-applications, webserver

I need to test my web application using the Apache web server. I need to do the testing on localhost.

What all steps do I need to follow for the setup? Like where to copy the testing folder locally, which files do I need to update in the Apache folder, etc

I have Apache2.2 running locally.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No special setup is required. Sencha Touch is basically a Javascript file you include in your HTMLs.

Add them to your public directory (by default htdocs), and then its a matter of adding the following lines into your HTML file, and start programming with the Sencha Touch API !

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="sencha-touch.css" >
<script type="text/javascript" src="sencha-touch-debug.js"></script>
```

Comment: Not sure if you have yourself tested it...But as far as I am aware, we need to have a web server for local testing of Sencha touch apps..So do you know how can I use Apache to setup the same ??

Comment: @hmthr Is this the reason for the downvote? As I have said in my post, you place the Javascript and CSS files in a directory being served by your local HTTP server, in this case Apache. Then, you just reference it as above in your HTML files and code as you would on a remote server.

Comment: So I want to understand how exactly do I set that up for local testing...I mean what all changes do I need to make under Apache ??

Comment: @hmthr As I've said in my post and comment, **no changes** need to be made. You simply copy-paste the JS and CSS files and link them in your HTML file and code with the Sencha Touch API.

Comment: Ok..forget about Sencha touch since I am not sure how it works for you locally...Can u tell me how do I setup Apache web server for local testing?

Comment: @hmthr , once you've set up Apache, start the service, and point your browser at http://localhost, http://127.0.0.1 or http://[::1]. As stated before, just place the files you wish to use into the htdocs directory (by default).

Comment: Thx..but as i am new to this, I'll require detailed steps..Also for your ref, Sencha touch does indeed require a web server for local testing..u can see http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/touch/getting-started.html